# Sharepoint Content query item style XSLT for article date

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

I need to create an item style for a content query webpart which aggregates news article from a news site(publishing site). The content query will pull Article date in "October 19" format, the comments field, and a link "Full story" linked to the news article page. How to get a basic item style XSLT to acheive this? I am new when it comes to XSLT. Can someone give me some ideas so I can get started on it?